# Talking to SMTP Server in C with send()

Tags: c, sockets, smtp

I'm programming an interactive SMTP Client, which can talk to an SMTP Server though the terminal. So far I've established a connection (server response 220 after first `recv()`), and then try to send a `HELO` to the Server. The send function gives me a return value of 15, so that should be working. But then I try to read the response (which should be `250 OK`), but the program blocks and returns nothing. I'm using fake SMTP as a testing Server.

Here is my code so far:

```
char IPADDRESS []= "127.0.0.1";

int initConnect(){

   int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,NULL, 0);

   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
   memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(25);
   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

   if(inet_pton(AF_INET, IPADDRESS, &serv_addr.sin_addr) > 0){

      connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

   }else{

      return -1;

   }

   return sock;

 }


 int main(void){

   char buffer[1024];

   memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
   int FLAGS = 0;

   int fd;
   fd = initConnect();

   if(fd == -1){

      printf("Error occured while connecting to the Server");
      exit(1);

   } else {

     printf("  ->   Connected\n");

   }

   // get response from Server after connection
   int recBytes =   recv(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), FLAGS);
   printf("Server: %s", buffer);

   // send HELO cmd to Sever (if < 0 error)
   int ret = send(fd, "HELO 127.0.0.1\n", strlen("HELO 127.0.0.1\n"), FLAGS);
   printf("\nSend bytes: %i\n", ret);

   // get response from Server after HELO (program blocks here)
   memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
   recBytes = recv(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), FLAGS);
   printf("\nServer: %s", buffer);
}
```

Comment: According the the spec each SMTP line should end with `<CR><LF>`. You are only sending `<LF>`.

Comment: That's it! Now it's working, thanks

Comment: On a side note, `setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,NULL, 0);` is not valid. You can't specify multiple socket options with a single call to `setsockopt()` like that. And both of those options take input values, which you are not passing in. You need to call `setsockopt()` for each socket option individually, eg: `int optval = 1; setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval)); setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &optval, sizeof(optval));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SMTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.8) says:

> Lines consist of zero or more data characters terminated by the
> sequence ASCII character "CR" (hex value 0D) followed immediately by
> ASCII character "LF" (hex value 0A).

Your code only sends `<LF>` (`\n`) so needs to be changed to `\r\n`.